# Best way to integration test with redux-saga

Tags: redux-saga

I'm working on a project which uses `redux-saga` to manage state changing from API calls.

I've seen plenty of examples of how to unit test a saga, but few examples that I can apply to actually do an integration test. We are using `jest` for the assertions.

I'd like to verify that when our user clicks save, the right action is dispatched, which calls the right saga, which then gets some data from our API, changing the state. I want to test the whole flow. If the API is mocked then that is fine.

The code was originally in Typescript but changed it to normal JS for simplicity. We are using `typescript-fsa` to create the actions, that is what the `actionCreator` refers to.

I have no idea how to actually test the saga given a certain action. In this case, what kicks it all off is a `FETCH_ITEMS_STARTED` action. That triggers the watcher which calls `handleFetchItems`. That defers to another generator, which yields a promise which is resolved when the API call completes, and should dispatch a `FETCH_ITEMS_DONE` action with the result.

```
function* handleFetchItems (action) {
    yield call(
        helperGenerator, 
        action, 
        actionCreator,
        function (payload) {
            // more code goes here...
            return api.getItems(payload);
        }
    );
}

function* helperGenerator (action, actionCreator, callback) {
    let result = yield call(function () {
        return callback(action.payload);
    });
    yield put(actionCreator.done({
        params: action.payload,
        result
    }));
}

function* watcher () {
   yield takeEvery(items.started, handleFetchItems);
}
```

Comment: Check out [redux-mock-saga](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-mock-saga) npm package, it allows to test how sagas changes the state,  so it covers state/action/saga integrations.

Comment: I am using [redux-saga-test-plan](https://github.com/jfairbank/redux-saga-test-plan) to record my sagas and assert on the dispatched actions. See an example [here](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing.html)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still interested, I published [an article](https://medium.com/@vidzhel/exploring-unit-and-integration-testing-in-redux-saga-41af34d82033) on the topic. Here're some notes:

With `redux-saga-test-plan`

- you can perform unit testing
- you can create integration tests
- it's possible to test sagas in the context of an app's state. You can add reducer that will be used during an integration test, specify a static state, check final state.
- you're able to mock sagas' effect creators, therefore APIs
- you can test the whole root saga including all the children